# GeoServer:Rendering process failed java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: geoserver, geotools

I'm using GeoServer2.13.1 with SQLServer DataSet and war deployed on Tomcat8.5.31.

**After configuring dataStore while the preview Layer getting the following Exception**:

> Rendering process failed java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.geotools.jdbc.SQLDialect.decodeGeometryValue(Lorg/opengis/feature/type/GeometryDescriptor;Ljava/sql/ResultSet;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/vividsolutions/jts/geom/GeometryFactory;Ljava/sql/Connection;Lorg/geotools/factory/Hints;)Lcom/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry;
>   org.geotools.jdbc.SQLDialect.decodeGeometryValue(Lorg/opengis/feature/type/GeometryDescriptor;Ljava/sql/ResultSet;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/vividsolutions/jts/geom/GeometryFactory;Ljava/sql/Connection;Lorg/geotools/factory/Hints;)Lcom/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry;

**The following are the GeoServer web Logs:**

```
2018-06-13 12:51:39,248 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Rendering process failed
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:611)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:286)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:141)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.executeInternal(GetMap.java:653)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:285)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:131)
    at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getMap(DefaultWebMapService.java:320)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.geoserver.kml.WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.invoke(WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.java:38)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:62)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:36)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.getMap(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:867)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:270)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.geotools.jdbc.SQLDialect.decodeGeometryValue(Lorg/opengis/feature/type/GeometryDescriptor;Ljava/sql/ResultSet;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/vividsolutions/jts/geom/GeometryFactory;Ljava/sql/Connection;Lorg/geotools/factory/Hints;)Lcom/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry;
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.fireErrorEvent(StreamingRenderer.java:483)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:823)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:581)
    ... 131 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.geotools.jdbc.SQLDialect.decodeGeometryValue(Lorg/opengis/feature/type/GeometryDescriptor;Ljava/sql/ResultSet;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/vividsolutions/jts/geom/GeometryFactory;Ljava/sql/Connection;Lorg/geotools/factory/Hints;)Lcom/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry;
    at org.geotools.jdbc.SQLDialect.decodeGeometryValue(SQLDialect.java:848)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureReader.readNextFeature(JDBCFeatureReader.java:363)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureReader.hasNext(JDBCFeatureReader.java:305)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection$WrappingFeatureIterator.hasNext(ContentFeatureCollection.java:139)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.drawPlain(StreamingRenderer.java:2385)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(StreamingRenderer.java:1959)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:821)
    ... 132 more
```

Please any help to solve Exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is saying it can't find a concrete method for  `org.geotools.jdbc.SQLDialect.decodeGeometryValue()` and all it has is the abstract parent class. The `SQLDialect` is a class that each type of JDBC datastore overrides to allow GeoServer to talk to it in the variant of SQL that that database understands.

In your case the concrete method implementation is provided in `SQLServerDialect` so if it is not being found that suggests that you have not added (or have added the wrong version of) the [SQLServer plugin](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlserver.html#sqlserver-install).

For GeoServer 2.13.1 this will add a file called `gt-jdbc-sqlserver-19.1.jar` to the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Comment: I was using the old version of SQL server plugin, that's why I got the above error. After adding sqljdbc4.jar and sqlserver-19.1.jar to WEB-INF/lib issue got solved. Thanks for quickly reply @Ian.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error typically happens when one mixes a version of GeoServer with a different (older, newer) version of a plugin. In this case I'm guessing you have version X of GeoServer and version Y of the SQL Server plugin.
Make them match and the issue should go away.